# Find the countries having classes of both ordinary ships and cruisers

Tags: sql

Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)

Ships(name, class, launched)

Battles(name, date)

Outcomes(ship, battle, result)

The Classes relation includes the class name, type (bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser)

1. What to find out: [Find the countries having classes of both ordinary ships and cruisers]
2. I tried the following query :

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ds1.country 
      FROM (SELECT t2.country 
              FROM Classes t2 
             WHERE t2.type='bb'
            INTERSECT
            SELECT t3.country 
              FROM Classes t3 
             WHERE t3.type='bc') AS ds1
```

- i am getting the correct result but the query is failing test on second, checking database.

I am getting the result:
Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database.
* Wrong number of records (more by 2)

The result of Your query:

country

Gt.Britain

Japan

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d889a6

Comment: Have you a table of all countries?

Comment: @JoeTaras NO. I have listed all the tables.

Comment: Give us also the link where this task is written :)

Comment: If you add a table with countries you can work with exists function and so you can remove distinct construct. So, in this way, normalize your DB.

Comment: @joetaras that probably misses the point of the exercise - not that I know what the point of the exercise is

Comment: strange.. simple intersect query is correct in all way but when trying "dataset" approach, its failing. If i am running only sub-queries, its working fine.

[select t2.country from Classes t2 where t2.type='bb' 
intersect 
select t3.country from Classes t3 where t3.type='bc']

Comment: @Strawberry: Hi, we must propose a correct solution, to better experience of all SO users. So the DB is not normalized and the performance with DISTINCT are worst. The error with my solution doesn't happen (IHMO)

Answer (score 0):

Does MySQL support the INTERSECT command?

If not can you rewrite the query as a JOIN:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.country 
FROM Classes t2 
INNER JOIN Classes t3 
ON t2.country  = t3.country 
WHERE t2.type='bb'
AND t3.type='bc'
```

Comment: nop mysql does not support INTERSECT.
BTW i am writing in sql only and intersect is working fine. the only thing is 

this is working fine:
[select t2.country from Classes t2 where t2.type='bb' intersect select t3.country from Classes t3 where t3.type='bc'] 

but this is not working fine tough there is no difference in the two:
[SELECT DISTINCT ds1.country 
      FROM (SELECT t2.country 
              FROM Classes t2 
             WHERE t2.type='bb'
            INTERSECT
            SELECT t3.country 
              FROM Classes t3 
             WHERE t3.type='bc') AS ds1]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.country
  FROM classes c
 WHERE c.type IN ('bc','bb')
 GROUP
    BY c.country
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT c.type)=2;
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d889a6/3

Comment: Is it? This question was originally tagged with MySQL; I don't know any other SQL dialect.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag as it involved intersect which mysql doesn't support. Avoiding intersect both your solution and mine will work.

Comment: @Strawberry i am very new to sql could you help in finding a way like how to get the name of a characteristic (a name of a corresponding column in the table) in a column in my result set?

Comment: @learning Sorry, I don't know what you mean. Consider extending your original question with both what you know now, and the subsequent part of the problem - or asking a new question with a link back to this one.

Comment: @Strawberry its a general question not related to current query.
Ok i can give an idea what i need to ask using this query as an example, what i am asking is: i want a two column result-set of my query in which 1st column consist of "table columns" like (name, class, launched) in Ships table where as in the 2nd column i want corresponding values for a particular WHERE clause. i hope i am able to tell you what i am looking for :)

Comment: @learning No, you're not. And I'm afraid the comments section is simply inappropriate for this kind of discussion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22068876/how-to-get-the-table-column-names-as-entries-in-result-column-set

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by with aggregate function to check if any country has both types of ships.

```
SELECT    country
FROM      Classes
GROUP BY  country
HAVING    SUM(case when type='bb' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
AND       SUM(case when type='bc' then 1 else 0 end) >= 1;
```