# how to get the table column names as entries in result column set?

Tags: mysql, sql

The database scheme consists:

Table1(code, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)

1. What to do is:
   For the Table1 with the maximal code value from Table1 table, obtain all its characteristics (except for a code) in two columns:

   - The name of the characteristic (a name of a corresponding column in the PC table);
   - Value of the characteristic.

I don't have any idea how to get the table column names in my result column set.
The final result will look like:

```
chr value
col1    133
col2    80
col3    28
col4    2
col5    50
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an unpivot operation.  The simplest way is using `union all`.  However, the following is generally more efficient:

```
select (case when n.n = 1 then 'col1'
             when n.n = 2 then 'col2'
             when n.n = 3 then 'col3'
             when n.n = 4 then 'col4'
             when n.n = 5 then 'col5'
        end) as chr,
       (case when n.n = 1 then col1
             when n.n = 2 then col2
             when n.n = 3 then col3
             when n.n = 4 then col4
             when n.n = 5 then col5
        end) as value
from table t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all select 5
     ) n;
```

This is more efficient when your table is big or a complicated subquery.

The `union all` version is:

```
select 'col1', col1 from table t union all
select 'col2', col2 from table t union all
select 'col3', col3 from table t union all
select 'col4', col4 from table t union all
select 'col5', col5 from table t;
```

Comment: any other way where we could avoid using UNION ALL? its really boring to type all column names manually..

Comment: You can use `information_schema.columns` to extract the column names.  You can use either SQL or a spreadsheet to generate the code you need.

Comment: [Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1737d/5) of how to achieve this using a prepared statement and the INFORMATION_SCHEMA so not all columns need to be typed out. Although it does require all columns to have the same data type!

Comment: hey @GordonLinoff what to do if data types of columns are different?? union will not work in this case... and also i have only access prvlg to the database so i can not proceed in the way of INFORMATION_SCHEMA :(

Comment: @learning . . . Based on the question, I have to assume that the types *are* compatible (you want to put them into a single column).  In any case, if they are not, then convert them to strings.  You can actually do this by converting the first to a string in either method using `cast()`.  MySQL will then automatically convert the rest to a string, using some format that you may or may not like.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'col1', MAX(col1) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT 'col2', MAX(col2) FROM table1
UNION
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 'cd' as chr, cd as value 
FROM pc 
WHERE code = (SELECT max(code) FROM pc)

UNION

SELECT  'model' as chr, cast(model as varchar)as value 
FROM pc 
WHERE code = (SELECT max(code) FROM pc)

UNION

SELECT  'speed' as chr,cast(speed as varchar)  as value 
FROM pc 
WHERE code = (SELECT max(code) FROM pc)

UNION

SELECT  'ram' as chr, cast(ram as varchar) as value 
FROM pc 
WHERE code = (SELECT max(code) FROM pc)

UNION

SELECT  'hd' as chr, cast(hd as varchar)  as value 
FROM pc 
WHERE code = (SELECT max(code) FROM pc)

UNION

SELECT  'price' as chr,cast(price as varchar)  as value 
FROM pc 
WHERE code = (SELECT max(code) FROM pc)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select char, value
From 
(Select code,
cast(speed as varchar(20)) speed,
cast(ram as varchar(20)) ram,
cast(hd as varchar(20)) hd,
cast(model as varchar(20)) model,
cast(cd as varchar(20)) cd,
cast(price as varchar(20)) price
FROM pc
) src
UNPIVOT 
(value For char in (speed,ram,hd,model,cd,price)
) As unpvt
where 
code in (Select max(code) from PC)`
```